# Kill Db2 select statement after the declared time

Tags: select, db2, timeout, kill

In Db2 LUW 9.7, how to implement a query timeout?

When performing queries, is there is a 'timeout' parameter that I can declare/implement somehow that will make a given query abort after a certain time?

So far, I can only consider the potentially unsafe practice of killing the process that performs the select query in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about programming, it is about administration.

A query will never "kill itself".  But there are tools available which (after suitable configuration) will limit the resources that a query can consume at run time, and will cause the query to return an error (if desired) if such resources are exceeded.

You should never kill a process that is owned by a Db2-instance, doing that carries risk that you trash your database.

To control the resources (time, memory, CPU, disk, etc...) that a query can use, it is possible on V9.7 to use [Workload-Manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/c0052604.html#c0052604.dita__wlmfaq2). This requires configuration and experience to properly use it.

IBM also offered a [Query-Patroller](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.qp.topics.doc/doc/c0010446.html) tool before IBM introduced the Workload Manager (WLM). This was a different solution than WLM. I think Query Patroller was also available in V9.7. It has since been replaced by WLM.

Answer (score 0):

In principle there are two ways to achieve what you need, depending on whether you have the control over the application or the database.

From application end one can use [`SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0008809.html) keyword with CLI/ODBC or `setQueryTimeout` with JDBC (there should be an equivalent for other interfaces). I will attach CLI example at the end.

If you have only control over database then one could consider creating a threshold with [`ACTIVITYTOTALTIME`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.wlm.doc/doc/r0051922.html) that would automatically interrupt long running queries.

If you are concerned with Db2 CLP client, then interrupting execution with `ctrl+c` will propagate interrupt to the database, i.e. you should no longer see statement as executing inside the database. If you however break it more "forcefully" e.g. run `kill` against `db2bp` process associated with the shell, statement will continue executing for some time, but it will be  eventually interrupted (one will see `AgentBreathingPoint` Warning in db2diag.log, when Db2 engine periodically checks whether client is still around and it happens to be gone).

Db2 CLI example:

I will use

- `db2cli` executable - CLI to run Db2 CLI commands
- "bad query" that is expected to run for a long time:

`select t1.*, t2.* from sysibm.syscolumns t1, sysibm.syscolumns t2, sysibm.syscolumns t3, sysibm.syscolumns t4, sysibm.syscolumns t5 order by t5.name desc, t4.name asc fetch first 10 rows only`

- set the timeout to 10 seconds

code:

```
SQLAllocEnv 1
SQLAllocConnect 1 1
SQLConnect 1 SAMPLE sql_nts db2v115 sql_nts **** sql_nts
SQLAllocStmt 1 1
SQLSetStmtAttr 1 SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT 10
SQLPrepare 1 "select t1.*, t2.* from sysibm.syscolumns t1, sysibm.syscolumns t2, sysibm.syscolumns t3, sysibm.syscolumns t4, sysibm.syscolumns t5 order by t5.name desc, t4.name asc fetch first 10 rows only" sql_nts
SQLExecute 1
SQLFetch 1
SQLError 1 1 1
```

it is `SQLFetch 1` that will fail, full output including SQLCODEs below:

```
$ db2cli
IBM DATABASE 2 Interactive CLI Sample Program
(C) COPYRIGHT International Business Machines Corp. 1993,1996
All Rights Reserved
Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
> SQLAllocEnv 1
SQLAllocConnect 1 1
SQLConnect 1 SAMPLE sql_nts db2v115 sql_nts *** sql_nts
SQLAllocStmt 1 1
SQLSetStmtAttr 1 SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT 10
SQLAllocEnv: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
             CLI henv = 1, Test Driver henv = 1
> SQLAllocConnect: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
             CLI hdbc = 1, Test Driver hdbc = 1
> SQLConnect: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
> SQLAllocStmt: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
              CLI hstmt = 1, Test Driver hstmt = 1
> SQLSetStmtAttr: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
> SQLPrepare 1 "select t1.*, t2.* from sysibm.syscolumns t1, sysibm.syscolumns t2, sysibm.syscolumns t3, sysibm.syscolumns t4, sysibm.syscolumns t5 order by t5.name desc, t4.name asc fetch first 10 rows only" sql_nts
SQLPrepare: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
> SQLExecute 1
SQLExecute: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
> SQLFetch 1
SQLFetch: rc = -1 (SQL_ERROR) 
> SQLError 1 1 1
SQLError: rc = 0 (SQL_SUCCESS) 
SQLError: SQLState     : S1008
          fNativeError : -952
          szErrorMsg   : [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/6000] SQL0952N  Processing was cancelled due to an interrupt.  SQLSTATE=57014

          cbErrorMsg   : 100
```

Answer (score 0):

ODBC/CLI: [QueryTimeout](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0057060.html)

JDBC: The `commandTimeout` property.
[Common IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ properties for all supported database products](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html)

> if I kill the process that performs the select query in Unix then the query should also be aborted

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

create a threshold on ACTIVITYTOTALTIME or UOWTOTALTIME and set action on stop execution

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050563.html